# Has anyone gotten OQTANE to work behind an AWS Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, blazor

We have a working non-ssl hello world Oqtane application behind an AWS ALB.

SSL Terminates at the ALB, and we are forwarding traffic to the EC2 instance over port 80.

We get an "application may no longer respond" error in the browser, and Firefox Network tools indicate

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (oqtane.cmrus.com:443)
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at ...

No problem with standard html apps, or standard Blazor apps (not using websockets).

It seems like the HTTP request to open the web socket dies on the vine.  If anyone has managed to get this to work, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this issue was due to our running Oqtane server in conjunction with Oqtane webserver and Blazor.  We had a hosts file entry on the local server referencing the private IP.  Once we removed that entry, the system started working.